# Suggestions for image database server with search engine

Tags: image, server, search-engine, 3d-model

I tried searching Google. Really, I did.

I am looking for a server that stores pictures/images/3D models, or read the images from some other source (like git or something like), and provides a search engine to those pictures, based on keywords or even based on the picture itself.

This is something similar to what Google Photos or Flickr do, but I need this in a closed environment, that's why those won't work for me. So I need a server/software that I can use on my own infrastructure. Open source or proprietary, doesn't matter.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you looking for a solution as a service or going to build your own solution?

Comment: Looking for a ready solution where I can host on my own server, maybe on AWS or something else.